# Does anyone know how to change the iPhone settings from interior of an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Does anyone know how to change the iPhone settings for an app? For example : the on or off switch for a notification in an app.

Comment: Do you mean the settings for your app or some of the system preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done from within your app. You can however use a URL scheme to open the preferences from your app (i.e. leave your app and open the preferences)

[This link should provide more information](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-using-url-schemes-to-open-the-settings-app-to-a-specific-page-in-ios-5/)